# Asynchronous function call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, callback

My problem is this .I am new to javascript. I have a function which makes an asynchronous call to a Google map API (which returns location based on latlng) .This function in my code is **MarkerCreaterPlusLocation**. This call returns a value which I need in another function which is named **MarkerCreater** in my code. But the problem is that **MarkerCreater** does not stop for the **MarkerCreaterPlusLocation** to return the value .

To overcome this problem I tried using the callback for the **MarkerCreater** to get executed when the asynchronous function returns the value

The structure is as follows :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click',addLatLng); //This code attaches the function to Listener



function addLatLng(event) {
        path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(event.latLng);
        MarkerCreaterPlusLocation(event.latLng,MarkerCreater);//MarkerCreater is the callback function
}




function MarkerCreaterPlusLocation(input,callback){
    location="l";
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': input}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        location=results[1].formatted_address;
        callback(location,input);//I call the callback function upon the success of the result or otherwise
      } else {
        location="l"; 
        callback(location,input);
      }
    } else {
      location="l";
      callback(location,input);
    }
    });
}




function MarkerCreater(l,x){

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: x,
        title: '#' + path.getLength()+l,
        icon: 'images/beachflag.png',
        map: map
});
    ///Some more javascript code 
}
```

I guess I am making mistake here as this does not seem to work . Rather it gives a 404 error which makes it still more difficult for me to understand it . Please help

Comment: You have a syntax error ... but maybe it's just a copy/paste issue. There is an additional "s" after `location="l"` in MarkerCreaterPlusLocation()

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error . I have corrected it . Yeah it was a copy paste error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `location` variable is not declared with `var`, which means it's in the global scope (i.e. window). So, setting `location` is actually setting `window.location`, which is causing the redirect to a 404.

To fix this, change the first line of your MarkerCreaterPlusLocation function to:

```
var location="l";
```

This will create it in the scope of the function only, and not the window.

Comment: Thanks !! s was copy-paste error . The error was with the declaration of location variable .

Comment: Great. Always a good idea to declare your variables with `var` to avoid problems like this, unless you _really_ want to create a global variable.

Comment: FYI - That doesn't seem to work in Chrome.  Better not to use "location" as a variable.

Comment: Works in latest Chrome/Mac for me, when the var declaration is inside a function. But you're right, better to not use it at all!